# Grub Read error : I think I have a hard drive problem, but I'm not sure?

Tags: kernel, grub

One year ago, I got a big grub problem on my laptop (an old Lenovo), with dual boot windows/unbuntu. I spend one entire day to repair that and I finished by reset my computer and install Pop Os (without dual boot). It have resolved the problem (I was thinking at this time).

Now, I have used Pop Os until I have a new grub problem that is quite weird : my laptop run the os 1/3 time, the other time I have a grub problem. I searched to resolve that the entire day yesterday, I reset it and I have now the same problem.

There are here very weird things, and I just want to know if I can fix that or if this is a problem with the hard drive (wich I suspect).

So, when I run my compute I have 3 options :

- That run correcty the OS
- I have a "Read Error" and no grub rescue, I have to force shutdown manually
- I have a grub rescue, and when I navigate in the partition that sometimes work or indicate "Unknow file system" (on the same partition, the same command can do both !)

This is a try to repair grub on grub rescue (msdos3 is a boot partition, the os partition is msdos2).

```
error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hdo'.
Entering rescue mode...

grub rescue> ls (hd0, msdos3)
(hd8, msdos3): Filesystem is ext2.

grub rescue> ls (hd0, msdos3)/
./../ lost+found System.map-5. 11.8-7633-generic config-5. 11.8-7633-generic ini
trd. img initrd. img-5. 11.8-7633-generic initrd. ing. old vmlinuz vmlinuz-5.11.8-763
3-generic vmlinuz.old grub/ vmlinuz-5.13.0-7614-generic config-5.13.0-7614-gener
ic System.map-5. 13.0-7614-generic initrd. img-5. 13.0-7614-generic

grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0, msdos3)/grub

grub rescue> set root=(hd0, msdos3)

grub rescue> insmod normal

error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hdo'.
```

What do you think about that ? Is it fixable for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Worst case, this might be your only warning that your disk is about to die. Make sure you have anything important backed up, **right now**.

After that, start by checking the SMART disk health information, by `smartctl -x /dev/sda` (or whatever your device is), or by e.g. [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/download/#CrystalDiskInfo) in Windows. But remember that the SMART is not all-knowing: a disk might fail even if SMART says it's OK.

Another possibility is that the power capacitors in your old laptop are starting to lose their capacity, and the symptoms are caused by them not always being quite able to deliver enough amperage to the disk at boot time to get it properly spun up in the expected time (the "Read error" case, possibly). In this case, your data is probably fine; you'll just need to remove the disk and plug it into another computer to recover your files, which can be a pain if you aren't prepared for that.

Or, since this is an old laptop, you might have multiple things near failure at the same time.

Replacing the disk with a newer one with lower power consumption (lower wattage/amperage rating) might be a way to prolong the life of the old laptop some more, if you are on a tight budget.